# copy data from Previous non null rows and if first row is null copy next non null value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to copy data from rows with non-null rows and if first row is null copy the next non-null value.

it is not a big table. There is no ID column and date column.

The datatype of this column is varchar.

I am using SQL Server 2012

This is how the data is in the table:

| Masked |
| --- |
| 5574-12XX-XXXX-1338 |
| 6674-13XX-XXXX-0855 |
| 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237 |
| Null |
| Null |
| Null |
| 9984-11XX-XXXX-6196 |
| 3384-11XX-XXXX-0615 |
| Null |
| Null |

This is expected result.

| Masked |
| --- |
| 5574-12XX-XXXX-1338 |
| 6674-13XX-XXXX-0855 |
| 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237 |
| 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237 |
| 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237 |
| 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237 |
| 9984-11XX-XXXX-6196 |
| 3384-11XX-XXXX-0615 |
| 3384-11XX-XXXX-0615 |
| 3384-11XX-XXXX-0615 |

online solutions work with simple data. but I am struggling with this data. I am very desperate for the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack. Can you explain more about your question and add your query, table.

Comment: Please see [help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) for how to add details that we need.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a [mcve] to your question.  Use the [edit] link at the bottom of the question to add the details to your question.

Comment: By definition, rows in a table have no particular order. Your task is impossible if there is no column (or set of columns) that can be used in an order by clause to determine the order you desire. So - does that column (or set) exist?

Answer (score 1):

For that you need an ORDER and another column that helps get the last number

the cte #help1 get you the order with Row# needed for the following tables
ChangeIndicator is need t make a group , s that you can get the corect masked value

In #help2 the groupy are established, so that you can get the first vaule of the group, which has the value, you want fr that you need also the order built in #help1.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     ([Masked] varchar(19))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     ([Masked])
> VALUES
>     ('5574-12XX-XXXX-1338'),
>     ('6674-13XX-XXXX-0855'),
>     ('7784-14XX-XXXX-5237'),
>     (NULL),
>     (NULL),
>     (NULL),
>     ('9984-11XX-XXXX-6196'),
>     ('3384-11XX-XXXX-0615'),
>     (NULL),
>     (NULL)
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> WITH #help1 as (
> select *
> ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Row#
> , case when [Masked] is null then 0 else 1 end as ChangeIndicator
> from [dbo].[table1]
> )
> , #help2 as (
> select *, Sum(ChangeIndicator) over (ORDER BY Row#) RowGroup from #help1
> )
> select 
> case when [Masked] is not null then [Masked]
> else first_value([Masked]) over (partition by RowGroup ORDER BY Row#)
> end UnitsBalanceFillDown
> from #help2
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | UnitsBalanceFillDown |
> | :------------------- |
> | 5574-12XX-XXXX-1338  |
> | 6674-13XX-XXXX-0855  |
> | 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237  |
> | 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237  |
> | 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237  |
> | 7784-14XX-XXXX-5237  |
> | 9984-11XX-XXXX-6196  |
> | 3384-11XX-XXXX-0615  |
> | 3384-11XX-XXXX-0615  |
> | 3384-11XX-XXXX-0615  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4fb5aacebf743ee0cbb818ba859f9603)*